# GZip completely breaks CSS

Tags: css, gzip

I am trying to compress a CSS file (Foundation Framework 4). The file is massive so it can help speed up my website considerably, but everytime I gzip it, my website loads as if there are no stylesheets at all.

Any help please? <3

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring a compressed CSS file is exactly the behavior I'd expect. Most browsers don't know how to unzip a file, so they just look at the zipped file, don't know what to do with it, and say "this CSS file is malformed; I'm ignoring it". There are ways to make a CSS file a little smaller - mostly by stripping out unneeded whitespace - but for the most part you're stuck loading the whole thing. If it's taking too long to load, find some way to simplify it.

How big is this CSS file, anyway? If it's so big that loading it slows down your page loads, that's actually kind of impressive. And the user's browser should cache it after it's been loaded once and then not need to download it again on subsequent pages. Could it be slowing down not because of the load time, but because there are so many selectors that parsing and applying them all is a significant task? If so, you could probably improve things by breaking your CSS into separate files, and load only the ones you need on the current page.

Comment: Spliting the css is actually not a very good idea, cause it would just generate more http requests. I tried once to compress my css, and just gave up, it's not worth it. Compress your JS, not your CSS. What you can and should do, is get rid of not used selectors, that you probably have on loads, since you're using a framework. There's a extention to FF that does that, its called DUST-ME. (you just gotta be lucky enought that it works, sometimes it just infinitely loads)